# Is there a javascript framework that can help me implement the animation of venn diagram?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, visualization

For example, there is a two-circle venn diagram.

And there's a button. After clicking that, I can see how the venn diagram changes from the original one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, check [d3](http://d3js.org/) and related [applications](http://bl.ocks.org/1067616).